# Nest creating dto with class validator is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, nest

I have a simlple request that i am trying to build using class validator in nestjs but it is failing with error ` one of the parameter is missing in the request payload" any help here what is missing in creating new schema ?

main.model.ts

```
 export class IrxOrder {
    @IsString()
    readonly lineOfBusiness: string;
    @IsString()
    readonly memberIdentifier: string
}

export class ProcessRxOrderInfo {
    @IsString()
   emailAddress: string;
    @IsString()
    readonly sendCustomerEmail: string;
    @IsObject()
    @ValidateNested() @Type(() => IrxOrder)
    readonly rxOrder: IrxOrder[];
}



export default class CreateSubmitRequest {
    @IsObject()
    @ValidateNested() @Type(() => ProcessRxOrderInfo)
    readonly processRxOrderInfo: ProcessRxOrderInfo

}
```

Request:

```
{
  "processRxOrderInfo": {
    "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
    "sendCustomerEmail": "Y",
    "rxOrder": [
      {
        "lineOfBusiness": "mail",
        "memberIdentifier": "testJ"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class ProcessRxOrderInfo

```
@IsObject()
@ValidateNested() 
@Type(() => IrxOrder)
readonly rxOrder: IrxOrder[];
```

The validator `@IsObject` would result in the error your mentioned since it's actually supposed to be an array of objects rather than single object. I copied your code and simply removing it got the job done. You may choose to add `@IsArray()` validator here